# Change highlight panel in feed based layout

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console

I am having difficulty editing the highlight panel in an feed based layout. Apparently there is a difference between a standard layout highlight panel and a feed based highlight panel? In SF documentation it says:

> To remove fields, click the appropriate column and select -None- from
>   the field lists. To add columns, click Add Column. To remove columns,
>   hover over the column and click remove highlights panel column icon.

This applies to a standard layout highlight panel. Is this functionality lost completely when moving to a feed based layout?

**Sidenote:** Would I be able to create a custom highlight panel, and if so, could you point me in the right direction? Would I need to use the console integration toolkit? My Google skills haven't returned any results so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. There are some slight differences between highlight panels for feed layouts and non-feed layouts. In standard (non-feed) layout you can remove columns entirely as the docs suggest. In feed layouts you gain the ability to add labels to the columns but cannot explicitly remove columns. However, if you set all the fields in a column to --None-- for a feed layout, the remaining columns will expand to fill the space as if that column was removed.

If you want to create a custom highlight panel, you can do so. You would add a custom console component in the Top sidebar slot for a primary tab. There are more details about adding console components to a layout here https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_components_create_page_layouts.htm

Comment: That explains it, thanks for the tip about custom console components!